# Storage Engine:Memory For Cart Management in eCommerce Site

Tags: mysql, memory, database-design, storage-engines

I am using Storage Engine:Memory for Cart Management in Shopping website.
For Inserting, Updating, and Removing Items from Cart.

So My Question is how preferable to use Storage Engine:Memory in MySQL. I know it flashes data when server shutdown. But this table data is useful for only single day. Using Session, my code can be complex so i am thinking about this.

So I need some valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "cart" is lost, the customer is lost.  Are you willing to risk it?  If not, use InnoDB.

Complexity of code should not be much different; what concerns you?

When does a "day" end?  At midnight on *your* server?  What if someone on the other side of the world is starting a cart just before your midnight?

On the other hand, it may be *wise* to store credit card numbers (and other sensitive info) in `MEMORY` as a small step toward security.  If so, store it in a separate table so only that is lost.